# disable button while retrieving data from local storage and updating the date input

Tags: javascript, html, json, local-storage

I am trying to implement a function that checks if the date and time I choose have already been chosen before, if so, it gives an error, if not it lets me carry on with adding the ticket. The current function does save options to local storage, however it looks like it doesn't retrieve them for me and allows me to choose the same date twice.

```
var count = 0;
function store() {

  let clickCounter = localStorage.getItem("clickCount");
  if (!clickCounter) {
    localStorage.setItem("clickCount", 0);
    clickCounter = "0";
  }
  clickCounter = parseInt(clickCounter);
  document.getElementById('inc').value = ++count;
  if (clickCounter == 100) {
    console.log("Limit reached");
    return;
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("clickCount", clickCounter + 1);
  }
  console.log("Saving");
  var e = document.getElementById("time");
  var time = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  var date = document.querySelector("input").value;

  localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(time), date);

  console.log(localStorage);
  if (!localStorage.getItem("history")) {
    localStorage.setItem("history", "[]");
  }
  const history = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("history"));
  history.push({ [JSON.stringify(time)]: date });
  localStorage.setItem("history", JSON.stringify(history));
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("history"));

}

function myDate(date) {

  var today = new Date();
  var newDate = new Date(date);
  var nextWeek = new Date();
  var pastWeek = new Date();
  nextWeek.setDate(nextWeek.getDate() + 7);
  pastWeek.setDate(pastWeek.getDate() - 7);
  const dateInput = document.getElementById('date');

  if (newDate < pastWeek || newDate > nextWeek) {
    document.getElementById("time").disabled = true;
    console.log("error")

    return;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("time").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: You aren't even checking if the key exists.  try `if(!history[time]) { }` before you push into the history object

Comment: I've tried that, the main issue is looping through individual dates and times and seeing if I have already chose that and if so then I want to throw an error message or ideally disable the add button until I choose another date.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean, can you provide a codepen to recreate the error?